# Retrieving data from firebase for chat system

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase

Here is my firebase data - 
[image]

I store a copy of every message under both the users -

I have 2 questions. -

Q1 -  The query for extracting chat messages between user1 and user2 in an ordered fashion so it can be displayed in the personal chat window -

I wrote the following-

```
//refuser1 is firebase reference to "https://myapp.firebaseio.com/messages/user1"

var messages = [];        
refuser1.orderByChild("from").equalTo("user1").once('value', function(s){
s.forEach(function(childsnap){
messages.push(s.val());
});
});


refuser1.orderByChild("from").equalTo("user2").once('value', function(s){
 s.forEach(function(childsnap){
 messages.push(s.val());
 });
});
// Now messages array has all messages between user1 and user2 -
// add code to sort messages in array based on timestamp  /
```

Is this the correct way to store and retrieve data for personal one to one chat?

Q2 - When retrieving data , 'value' and 'child_added' events seem to act differently - See the image below - 
[image]
When i use `'value'` i get all the child objects but when I use `'child_added'` I get only the first child in users1 .
The documentaion says that child_added is triggered for every initial child (assuming this means all the child that were existing before new child is added)
Is my understanding correct? I was expecting the same returned result for 'value' and 'child_added'

Comment: Please copy/paste data - screenshots are hard to work with. Also, format your code. Value events grab everything at a node and delivers it to the app. If the node has 1000 children, you'll get them all at one time - iterate through them in code. Added event iterates over each child node once and delivers it to the app per child, it will then notify the app of any additional children added.

Comment: Also: if you have two questions, ask them separately. That way: people can answer each one separately.

Comment: Oh and you may want to look into the once(child_added). This will result in a single child added event and then the event listener will get removed so it will only result on one child being returned.

Comment: Answers below. For future questions: stick to one question per post and don't use screenshots of text. I now had to type something mimicking your JSON into my answer. If you had included the JSON as text, I could've copy/pasted it. A quick way to get your JSON in text format is to use the Export button in your Firebase dashboard.

Comment: Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen . I apologise for the screenshot, I will always paste text in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1) In NoSQL databases, you'll typically have to store the data in the way you want to use it. If you want to get the chat messages between specific users in a specific order, you should store them in that way.

```
chats
  user1_user2
    -K...c9
      from: "user1"
      message: "Hello message 1"
      time: ""
    -K...od
      from: "user1"
      message: "Hello message 2"
      time: ""
    -K...t8
      from: "user2"
      message: "Hello message 1"
      time: ""
    -K...c9
      from: "user1"
      message: "Hello message 1"
      time: ""
    -K...xb
      from: "user2"
      message: "Hello message 2"
      time: ""
```

In the above structure I've grouped the messages between `user1` and `user2` under a node `user1_user2`. This node serves as the "private chat room" between these two users: any time the same two users chat, their messages are added to this room.

Q2) You're doing `once('child_added'`. This means that you're telling Firebase to fire `child_added` only once and then to stop firing it. If you instead do `on('child_added'` it *will* be triggered for every initila child and all subsequent additions.